# Show related query terms using Solr

Tags: solr

I would like to show related query terms to the user.
For example, if I type "bmw" on Google, I get at the bottom:

```
Searches related to bmw
bmw prices
bmw 3 series
bmw motorcycles
bmw careers
bmw m3
bmw parts
bmw forum
bmw i8
```

I haven't found any build in feature to do so, is there anything I can use?

Answer (score 1):

There is no inbuilt feature for storing the queries.
If you want to suggest previous run queries as an autosuggest,

1. you would need to index the queries into a collection
2. The field then can be configured to have ngrams to provide related previous searches.